# How to typeset moon symbol in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, wasysym

I need to write a formula where the following symbol should appear as a subscript:

[image]

which is provided by `\usepackage{wasysym}`.

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}


Some random text $g_{\mbox{\leftmoon}}=1.623\,[m/s^2]$ and some more random text.
 

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the output is not the one I would get. How can it be solved?

Comment: This works fine for me. I think that `\mbox` actually leaves math mode and enters LR mode so you may need to add `$` inside the `\mbox` argument, like `\mbox{$\leftmoon$}`, although `\leftmoon` works in both math and text mode. On an unrelated note look into the `siunitx` package for typesetting units.

Comment: What about `$g_{\scalebox{0.6}{\leftmoon}}=1.623\,[m/s^2]$ `?

Comment: Use `_{\text{\leftmoon}}` in the place of \mbox.

Comment: Thank you you all. Each different solution works fine. Just one more question: since I have activated `\usepackage{wasysym}`, in some part of my document I get the following warning: `Font shape U/wasy/b/n in size <9> not available - Font shape U/wasy/m/n tried instead.` What does it mean? Why has it appeared only now?

Comment: It means there's no bold version of the font in size  9pt, so it uses the normal weight.

Comment: Alright @Bernard, thank you. But why did it appear in a part of the text where no symbol associated with `wasysym` has been used? I mean, the warning poped up as soon as I activated the `wasysym` package.

Comment: Perhaps you used a wasy symbol in a context where the font is supposed to be bold?

Comment: The error message you’re getting indicates that you’re using the symbol in a boldface context. Since there isn’t a boldface version of the font, LaTeX will fall back to the non-bold font.

Comment: The strange thing is that before using `wasysym` package, I didn't get the warning. Moreover, the warning is in another part of the text in correspondence of a `footnote` environment where a `\boldysmbol{\Psi}` is placed, and the symbol still appears bolded. I can't tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\text`, but it's better to define a proper command. The `\normalfont` command is meant to avoid spurious warnings for missing fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mathleftmoon}{}{{\text{\normalfont\leftmoon}}}

\begin{document}

Some random text $g_{\mathleftmoon}=\SI{1.623}{\meter\per\square\second}$
and some more random text.

$\mathleftmoon$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `1.623\,[m/s^2]` is wrong under at least two respects:

1. units should not be in brackets;
2. unit symbols should be upright.

Use `siunitx` and be happier.

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg, before accepting your answer, I just want to inform you that warnings about `Font shape [...] not available` still persist, even after using your `\NewDocumentCommand`. Have you any idea why these kind of warnings do not go away?

Comment: @Catarella What shape is not available?

Comment: `Font shape U/wasy/b/n' in size <9> not available(Font) -- Font shape U/wasy/m/n' tried instead.` The same message is repeated for `size <5>,<6> and <8>. ` in other parts of the text. This happened since I've activated `\usepackage{wasysym}`, before doing it, I didn't received any warnings about those shapes. It seems to be linked to `\chi` and `\Chi` when inserted in `\boldsymbol` or `\footnote` environments. @egreg

Comment: @Catarella I get no such warning, so it must depend on other symbols and other situations. Impossible to debug without information. Anyway, they are harmless warnings.